# l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables change language on buttons like withButtons

Tags: angularjs, datatable

In this datatables We add buttons like this

```
        $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
            .withDOM('frtip')
            .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
            .withDOM('Zlfrtip')
            //.withOption('rowCallback', rowClickCallback)
            .withButtons ([
                {
                    text: '<i class="fa fa-user-plus" style="margin-right:5px;"></i>' + $filter('translate')('users.addUser'),
                    key: '1',
                    action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
                        $scope.addUser ();
                    }
                }
            ])

        ;
```

As You can see we try to insert translate functionality from angular, but only get language on first load of the VIEW.

Text of tools like title for search box, pagination texts like next or prev etc. all is translating well using an external JSON

But withButtons only set language  on first load of view and do not change any more with language change like text of tools do.

And a question related to this:

How could I translate this buttons we added this way:
        $scope.dtOptions
            .withButtons([
                'copy',
                'print',
                'csv',
                'pdf',
                'excel'
            ]);

using angular translate.

Thanks in advance